# Change pull to refresh text color with swift

Tags: colors, swift, pull-to-refresh

I have a pull to refresh in my app.

How do i change the text color of the attributedTitle ?

```
 refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "hey ! is there something new ?")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
var attr = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.greenColor()]
refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "hey ! is there something new ?", attributes:attr)
```

Latest **Swift 5.6**

```
var attr = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "hey ! is there something new ?", attributes:attr)
```